# How to create egg shape physics body with CGPathRef?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgpath, skphysicsbody

[image: egg path]

I have to create a CGPathRef to simulate the physic property in Sprite Kit.

I am trying to create an egg shape path by an half of circle plus half of oval.
the egg's ratio is 0.4(bottom of half circle) to 0.6 (upper of half oval);
However, I don't know why nothing is happen.
following code is the creation of the path:

```
    self.egg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:IMAGE_NAME_EGG];
    [self.egg setScale:0.2];
    self.egg.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height - self.egg.size.height/2);
    self.egg.name = IMAGE_NAME_EGG;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 0, self.egg.size.height*0.4, self.egg.size.width/2, M_PI, M_PI_2, NO);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, self.egg.frame);
    self.egg.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:path];
    self.egg.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.egg.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = eggCategory;
    self.egg.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = floorCategory;
    self.egg.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = floorCategory;
    //self.eggCanMove = NO;
    self.egg.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    [self addChild:self.egg];
```

Comment: Your drawing code is certainly not going to give you an egg (for one thing, you are using CGPathAddEllipseInRect incorrectly). What I would do is just try to draw the egg into an ordinary UIView (as its `drawRect:`). Once you have code for a path that works to draw the egg, it will be a lot more obvious what to do.

Comment: Matt:
How to Add half of oval path??

Comment: How indeed. But that has nothing to do with sprite kit.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this. Make a texture of your egg with p.e. Adobe Illustrator and use this method:

```
init(texture texture: SKTexture!,alphaThreshold alphaThreshold: CFloat,size size: CGSize) -> SKPhysicsBody
```

1. The `SKTexture` is your egg image. The body is defined by the colored pixels.
2. The `alphaThresHold`: The minimum alpha value for texels that should be part of the new physics body.
3. The `Size` is clear I think.

The texture is analyzed and all invisible pixels around the egg are ignored and only the color pixels are interpreted as the body of the `SKPhysicsNode`.
You shouldn't use too many of these because they are very expensive to calculate for the Physics Engine.

Variations of this method are found in the [SpriteKit Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:size:).

Comment: Note that this requires iOS 8.0 or later.

Comment: None of this is ios specific either. Spritekit is cross platform